# How to custom JSON output of relation OneToMany in JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey(JAX-RS) to build a Rest application. Currently, I want to avoid child data to fetch the list of parent data. Because data child is very big, it will make the program very slowly when getting all list data parent. Currently, i use FetchType.EAGER, because if use FetchType.LAZY, i don't know the way to implement (Error is LazyInitializationException).

Pojo Structure;

```
class Parent  {
    ..
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval="true")
    private List<Child> listOfChildren;

    ..
    }
class Child {
    ..
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;
    ..
    }
```

How can custom to ignore Child data when getting list of parent data like bellow:

```
   [
        {
           "id": "0001",
           "name": "A",
           "listOfChildren":[
            // I want it is null because data is very big
           ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "name": "B",
            "listOfChildren":[
             // I want it is null, because data is very big
            ]
        },
        ..................
    ]
```

Fetch data list of parent like this:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Query q = em.createQuery("Select p from Parent p", Parent.class);
List<Parent> parents = q.getResultList();
Return Response.ok(parents).build();
```

But when i get only a parent record, it can get full data of children like bellow:

```
   {
        "id": "0001",
        "name": "A",
        "listOfChildren":[
           {
            "id": "01",
            "imagebase64": "data1"
           },
           {
             "id": "02",
             "imagebase64": "data2"
           }
         ]
    },
```

I am stuck, I hope every one can help me.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It's not good practice to return entity objects, so you should make 'info' objects just for returning in response. And for ignoring fields look for @JsonIgnore annotation.